# How to pull some information from a string with Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm just starting to play around with BeautifulSoup and I'm trying to create something in Python but when I scrape for the information the tags are included in the results which I do not want, is there anyway I can seperate the product ID from the tags?

Example of my results:

```
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
<product-id type="integer">8422899464</product-id>
```

Comment: Use the `string` property of the tag. `[i.string for i in soup.find_all('product-id')]`

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this if you want to get the data of product-id:

```
data = soup.find('product-id').getText()
print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[i.text for i in soup('product-id')]
```

out:

```
['8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464',
 '8422899464']
```

Comment: Is this the only line you used? When I try this is my code it only comes out with one line

Comment: @JakeMills I use jupyter notebook, it has some build in function to format the output.